Calculating expectation by manipulating into the MGF

Given that the moment generating function of the random variable X is
$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{1-2t}$, calculate the expectation of $Y^n,n\in \mathbb{N} $, where
$Y=365 \times 0.3^X$.

Here is my attempt. Use the definition to get:
$$E(Y^n)=E(365^n\times 0.3^{nX})$$
Move the constant outside, and use $x=e^{\text{ln } x}$
$$=365^nE(e^{\text{ln } 0.3^{nX}})$$
Use the power rule in logarithms to get:
$$=365^nE(e^{nX \text{ ln } 0.3})$$
Which by comparision with the definition of the moment generating function $M_X(t)=E[e^{tx}]$ is then
$$=365^n M_X(n \text{ ln } 0.3)$$
And then using the definition of $M_X(t)$ given in the question:
$$E(Y^n)=\frac{1}{1-2(n \text{ ln } 0.3)}$$
Is this correct?
Also, is there a way to find the underlying PMF/PDF?

Your derivation looks correct to me! To find the pdf, you could use that the MGF for $X$ describes a $\chi^{2}$ random variable with 2 degrees of freedom (compare with the general MGF here). Since the mapping $x \mapsto 365 \times 0.3^{x}$ is monotone for $x\in (0,\infty)$, you can obtain the pdf of $Y$ using a change of variables.
